# bold math with hat

Tags: unicode-math, boldmath

I'm struggling with a case of (silently) disappearing hat. It works fine on one computer, but on another I don't see the first accent:

```
\documentclass[border=3mm,preview]{standalone}

\usepackage[math-style=TeX]{unicode-math}
\setmathfont{xits-math.otf}

\begin{document}
\[
\mathbf{\hat d}, \mathbf{d}, \hat d
\]
\end{document}
```

[image]

I've just upgraded to MacTeX 2017 to see if that would help, but no luck. `unicode-math` just doesn't seem to like the bold math hat. Is there a good workaround? I should mention that I'm using xetex, and the intended main font would be `Source Sans Pro`.

Comment: Try `\symbf` instead of `\mathbf`.

Comment: Or do `\setmathfontface\mathbf{xits-bold.otf}` and enjoy the misplaced hat.

Comment: actually, both solutions give me a misplaced hat (right and left, respectively). What's going on?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I'd like to suggest that you do yourself a big favor and download and install the [STIX Two](http://stixfonts.org/) text and math fonts. The STIX Two fonts are much nicer and better designed that either the Stix or the XITS fonts.

The following code runs under both XeLaTeX and LuaLaTeX.

[image]

```
\documentclass[border=3mm,preview]{standalone}
\usepackage[math-style=TeX]{unicode-math}
\setmathfont{STIX Two Math}
\begin{document}
\( \mathrm{d}, d, \hat{d}, \symbf{d}, \hat{\symbf{d}}, \symbf{\hat{d}} \)
\end{document}
```

Comment: thanks! it works well on this example, unfortunately for my longer document I'm getting a dreaded `! Internal error: bad native font flag in `map_char_to_glyph'` and I'm not even sure which section is the problem

Comment: @baptiste - Please try to narrow down where the problem is occurring and then post a representative part of the problematic code.

Comment: I found the issue and solved it; I'd inherited some weird `{\hat {\mathbf {\theta }}}` from somewhere, and those were the problem. The document compiles now, and looks mostly good. One slight issue is the hat's position on bold theta, `\symbf{\hat{\theta}}` is a bit off.

Comment: @baptiste I get no displacement with XITS Math. Unfortunately the STIX Two Math font seems to be plagued by small bugs.

Answer (score 4):

You can use the command \boldsymbold which is in the amsmath package.

```
\documentclass[12pt,a4paper,oneside,titlepage]{scrartcl}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\begin{document}
$\hat{d}$ 
$\boldsymbol{\hat{d}}$
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Welcome to [TeX.SX](https://tex.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/1436/welcome-to-tex-sx)! Thanks for taking your time to answer a question. Here you can find some helpful [tips on how to make your answer great](https://tex.stackexchange.com/help/how-to-answer great) for the future.

Comment: thanks, but that doesn't seem to work well with other math fonts